# Where can I find a complete list of characters that are considered word boundaries in macOS?

Tags: copy-paste, text, text-editor, text-input

When one double clicks words in macOS usually the entire word is selected. For example, double clicking the phrase "this_is_a_word" will select the entire phrase as a singular word, but when you double click a section of the phrase "this-is-not-a-word" then only the actual words in this phrase between dashes will be selected.

Where can one find a list of all characters that are considered "word boundaries" in macOS that are used to define this behavior for selection?

It appears that there are many non-standard characters besides normal characters that might be considered word boundaries that are not, seemingly, fully documented...

So far I have come up with the following Unicode characters that all act as "word boundary" characters:

```
 '(),-.\/:;<=>[]{}«»*+÷&|^$%#@!~?Ý¥¶§®½¼¾¯´×¦¬¢¨¿¤¹²³©£¡¸°±·
```

Comment: Look to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756) for the answer.  It’s defined by the regex word boundaries.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not appear that there's a comprehensive actual list, but only the actual regular expression for such. I'm looking for the entire and complete set of Unicode characters as such.